# Unity - "There is no Animator attached to game object but script is trying to access it" error?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, computer-science

I have a script where Im trying to have two Animator objects having 1 to run the fade in and fade out states for the text and when the text is on the idle/finished state it then should have the other animator run the animations for the logos fade in/out but it returns the error above and I'm not sure why as both of my Animator objects are defined in the unity editor?

Can someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong >~< *snif*

```
    public Animator animText;
public Animator animLogo;

public GameObject Logo;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    animText = GetComponent<Animator>();
    Logo.SetActive(false);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    if(this.animText.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("GWSTxtIdleFin"))
    {
        animLogo = GetComponent<Animator>();
        animLogo.Play("LogoFadeIn");
    }
}
```

}

*EDIT:* I did notice i didnt re-make it visible as well btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because animtor is already in animLogo and animText  then remove these lines: `animLogo = GetComponent<Animator>();` and `animText = GetComponent<Animator>();`

Comment: I appear to have an issue where
        if(this.animLogo.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("LogoFadeFinish")) 
        {
            Debug.Log("purrr!");
        }
doesnt actually print out but the name is correct and the controller links to the anim

Comment: @CapturedNight hey. Create boolean in your script and make it false in the start. Then at the end of your animation (while recording) tick that boolean (make it true in inspector). Then in your code check if boolean is true. If true then animation finished. You can animate variable change in your scripts and know if animation finished or something like that.